# How to export Grafana datasource with basic auth details and import it again?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I am not able to export data sources in Grafana with basic auth details.

As I searched on internet, people are downloading datasource JSON by URL `<grafana>/api/datasources` and uploading same way with another API.

I tried doing that. Everything works fine but for basic auth info, only `basicAuth: true` is downloaded from above rest call as JSON but not password info. So, importing that JSON does not create proper datasource in Grafana.

Is there a way to smoothly export then import JSON to Grafana for data sources?( Specially for Prometheus data sources)

Thanks in advance.

Updating my scenario here:

**What is the requirement:**
I want my Grafana data sources which have basic auth enabled to get exported and imported to client site:

**Why it is needed:**
It is needed because in my one use case, I configured Prometheus datasource with basic auth and tried exported as json and pushed to GIT. And with help of Jenkins (CI/CD), I needed them to be created/updated in UAT deployment and then to customers with same approach.

Everything was working fine until I did not enable basic auth in Prometheus. Once, I enabled, This continuous integration is breaking because Grafana in UAT and Clients are not working with Prometheus due to Auth issue (because basic auth configs are not exported in JSON):

Can anyone help me resolving this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cater my scenario,
I did found how to pass the password for the basic auth while importing datasource JSON in Grafana.

> Note: By defining password and basicAuthPassword under secureJsonData
> Grafana encrypts them securely as an encrypted blob in the database.
> The response then lists the encrypted fields under secureJsonFields.

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/http_api/data_source/

so I put my password manually in the JSON exported from Grafana like below and then pushed into GIT.

```
{
  "name": "ds_prometheus",
  "type": "prometheus",
  "url": "http://my-prometheus:8080",
  "access": "proxy",
  "basicAuth": true,
  "basicAuthUser": "user",
  "secureJsonData": {
    "basicAuthPassword": "password"
  },
  "isDefault": true,
  "jsonData":{"httpMethod":"POST","keepCookies":[],"timeInterval":"30s","queryTimeout":"120s","tlsSkipVerify":true}
}
```

So, whenever CI/CD runs, data sources are correctly populated in Grafana with correct credentials.

Answer (score 3):

No. Credentials are stored in `secureJsonFields` and these fields are not available via API. It is a feature not a bug - https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/20274.

Comment: I opened this enhancement with my scenario described: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/27843

Comment: @Moksh Did you read https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/20274: `However, due to security reasons we don't want to expose this sensitive information thru the API.`?

Comment: Yes. But this does not answer the use case. I mentioned it in enhancement request as well. Or you are saying my use case is invalid.?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use datasource configuration for database:

```yaml
datasources:

  - id: 123
    uid: "myUid"
    name: "myDatabaseName"
    type: "mssql"
    access: "proxy"
    url: "this.is.my.server:1433"
    user: "databaseUser"
    secureJsonData:
      password: "mySecretPlainPassword"
    database: "myDatabaseName"
    basicAuth: false
    jsonData:
        encrypt: "false"
```